# Does the Ruby on Rails CarrierWave gem work with Ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery, carrierwave

For some reason using the CarrierWave gem with Ajax doesn't seem to be working for me.  Am I doing something wrong?  I followed the 253 CarrierWave Railscast well and it works without AJAX but in my application I need to use AJAX.  Here is my code:

The params list after selecting a jpeg in the image file field:

```
Parameters: {"item"=>{"remote_image_url"=>""}}
```

new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@item, :url => create_item_path, :html => {:id => "create_item_form", :multipart => true}) do |f| %>
    <p>
      <%= f.file_field :image %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :remote_image_url, "or image URL" %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :remote_image_url %>
    </p>
    <%= f.submit "Save", :id => "save_button" %>
<% end %>
```

application.js

```
$("#create_item_form").submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: $(this).attr("action"),
      dataType: "script",
      data:  $("#destination_item").sortable('serialize') + "&" + $(this).serialize()
      });
      return false;
});
```

item.rb

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :image, :remote_image_url
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :item_sub
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

schema.rb

```
  create_table "item", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "image"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

I have the carrierwave gem in my gemfile and I haven't changed anything in the app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb.

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is nothing that can be done without a using a library like Uploadify.  This is because the XMLHttpRequest (AJAX) standard has no support for file uploads.  The only way you can really fake this is using an iFrame with Flash.  Uploadify is the best of these options, and it has the best documentation.  This is what has to be done on the client side (browser).  Uploadify really isn't a ruby gem, its a collection of flash and js to allow the browser to 'fake it'.

On the server side, you can use carrierwave to support the uploads, but you need a way to get them there from the client side.  Here is an extremely similar question which should give you the instructions that you need.

[Rails Carrier Wave with JQuery Uploader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363698/rails-carrier-wave-with-jquery-uploader)

Hope this helps,

Joe

Comment: Will you give me my bounty then?

Comment: As noted in the other answer below, unless you need to support older browsers [XHR2](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2) has supported `FormData` for some time now. It's worth trying that if it's available to you and only falling back to other libraries for legacy support.

Comment: At this point this answer is outdated. HTML5 has the FormData and File API's that allow file uploads via AJAX. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously/8758614#8758614) for more.

Answer (score 8):

You can now upload files through ajax without the use of external libraries by using FormData()

SEE: [LINK 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718664/is-it-possible-to-peform-an-asynchronous-cross-domain-file-upload) & [LINK 2](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/07/firefox-4-formdata-and-the-new-file-url-object/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't upload a file via ajax like that. You'll need something like:
http://www.uploadify.com/

Comment: Why can't it be done?  Is it because CarrierWave doesn't support Ajax submits? I'm trying to use the minimal amount of gems. Thanks

Comment: Because XMLHttpRequest doesn't support file uploads.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? My answer is the same as the accepted one, even answered before it. We now know that you can indeed use ajax to do a file upload in modern browsers, but if you want to support older ones (IE8), you'll still need a work-around.