# How to upload images from domain to sub domain in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, image-uploading, subdomain

I want to move images from domain ie example.com to img.example.com programmatically.

Please suggest me some helpful resources that help me to solve my problem

Comment: Please check this one, http://stackoverflow.com/a/4104760/767329

Comment: Look at help on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and please edit to add more info. It's unclear what you are asking, please post code that shows hat you have tried, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create an FTP account ,then copy the images using FTP check the following articles:

[How to copy a file on an FTP server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005388/how-to-copy-a-file-on-an-ftp-server)

[Uploading Files to FTP Server programmatically in ASP.Net using C# and VB.Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Uploading-Files-to-FTP-Server-programmatically-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)